# Set Interleave (strip) size of Windows Storage Spaces Mirrored Pool

Tags: windows, powershell, drives, virtual-disk

I'm trying to make a new Windows Storage Space with an interleave of 64kb versus the default of 256kb.

I made a new Mirrored Pool and then tried using the PowerShell Command:

```
New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName Pool_T -FriendlyName Disk_T -Interleave 65536 -Size 4GB
```

How do I verify that this worked correctly?

```
Get-StoragePool -FriendlyName Pool_T | Get-ResiliencySetting
```

Gives me the interleave of the pool, how can I get the ones of the storage space?

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-VirtualDisk -friendlyname Disk_T | fl
```

The above command gives the Interleave size of the new storage pool and verifies that the Interleave was set as requested during creation.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to how your code solves this problem?